# Is this Postgres EXCLUDE constraint equivalent to this UNIQUE constraint?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-12

## The constraints

Currently, a table on a Postgres version 12 DB has the following `EXCLUDE` constraint:

```
ALTER TABLE ONLY example_table
ADD UNIQUE CONSTRAINT example_table_range_excl EXCLUDE USING gist 
(service_id WITH =, customer_id WITH =, tstzrange(billing_start, billing_end) WITH &&);
```

This constraint is on a big table. When I run `pg_restore` for the DB, this statement takes 5 hours to complete. On a replica test DB, I dropped the `EXCLUDE` constraint and added this `UNIQUE` constraint:

```
ALTER TABLE example_table
ADD CONSTRAINT uc_example_table UNIQUE (service_id, customer_id, billing_start, billing_end);
```

## My test case

I ran the following test with each constraint in place. In each test, I got the expected/desired constraint violation on the final `UPDATE`. This leads me to believe the constraints are equivalent.

```
-- Step 1: Insert an initial row
INSERT INTO example_table 
(customer_id, service_id, billing_start, billing_end) VALUES
(1, 1, '2023-10-04 00:00:00+00', '2023-10-05 00:00:00+00');

-- Step 2: Insert another row without a billing_end
INSERT INTO example_table 
(customer_id, service_id, billing_start) VALUES
(1, 1, '2023-10-04 00:00:00+00') RETURNING id;

-- Step 3: Update the row from step 2 to have the same billing_end as the row from step 1
--...this should violate whichever constraint is currently applied
UPDATE example_table SET billing_end = '2023-10-05 00:00:00+00'
WHERE id = 590756786785677
```

Violation when the `EXCLUDE` constraint is applied:

```
ERROR:  conflicting key value violates exclusion constraint "example_table_range_excl"
DETAIL:  Key (service_id, customer_id, tstzrange(billing_start, billing_end))
=(1, 1, ["2023-10-04 00:00:00+00","2023-10-05 00:00:00+00")) 
conflicts with existing key 
(service_id, customer_id, tstzrange(billing_start, billing_end))
=(1, 1, ["2023-10-04 00:00:00+00","2023-10-05 00:00:00+00")).
SQL state: 23P01
```

Violation when the `UNIQUE` constraint is applied:

```
ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "uc_example_table"
DETAIL:  Key (service_id, customer_id, billing_start, billing_end)
=(1, 1, 2023-10-04 00:00:00+00, 2023-10-05 00:00:00+00) already exists.
SQL state: 23505
```

## Performance?

If they are equivalent, would the `UNIQUE` constraint be more performant than the `EXCLUDE` constraint? It takes a minute to execute the `UNIQUE` constraint on this replica DB and applying the `EXCLUDE` constraint takes more than 10 minutes (I'm waiting for it to finish executing as I write this).

Answer (score 0):

These constraints aren't equivalent. Take this test case:

```
-- Step 1: Insert an initial row
INSERT INTO example_table 
(customer_id, service_id, billing_start, billing_end) VALUES
(1, 1, '2023-10-04 00:00:00+00', '2023-10-05 00:00:00+00');

-- Step 2: Insert another row without a billing_end
INSERT INTO example_table 
(customer_id, service_id, billing_start) VALUES
(1, 1, '2023-10-04 00:00:00+00') RETURNING id;

-- Step 3: Update the row from step 2 to have an overlapping billing time range with the row from step 1
--...this should violate whichever constraint is currently applied
UPDATE example_table SET billing_end = '2023-10-04 12:00:00+00'
WHERE id = 590756786785677;
```

- The `EXCLUDE` constraint yields a violation for this test case because 12 hours overlap between the billing time ranges.
- The `UNIQUE` constraint doesn't yield a violation because the combination of columns are distinct between the rows.